# Is it possible for a c compiler to transform an 'if-elseif' bloc into a 'switch' bloc to optimize the code?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

Is it possible for a c compiler to transform an 'if-elseif' bloc into a 'switch' bloc to optimize the code ?

The following code :

```
if ( a == 1 ) {
  bloc1
} else if ( a == 2 ) {
  bloc2
} else if ( ... ) {
....
} else if ( a == n ) {
  bloc n
}
```

during compilation is transformed to :

```
switch(a) {
  case 1:
    bloc1
    break;

  case 2:
    bloc2
    break;
  ...
  case n:
    blocn
    break;
}
```

If it is possible every time it is feasible, is there again an advantage of 'if...elseif' blocs on 'switch' blocs ?

Comment: There is no "switch" in the machine code generated by the compiler. But yes, the compiler may produce any code that it thinks that is executed faster. On the other hand it is possible that your two program snippets result in identical or at least very similar machine code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: I think OP means some code which executes in constant time using a jump-table or similar (some CPUs have special instructions for that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A compiler translates C code to machine code. On assembler level, there is no such thing as `if`, `else` or `switch`. There are just conditional branches and non-conditional branches.

So, no, the compiler will never do anything like what you are suggesting, because an `if-else` that can be replaced by a `switch` will already result in identical machine code, no matter which one you wrote. There is no middle "convert C to C" step.

For this reason, `switch` is kind of an obscure language feature, since it is in theory completely redundant. It is subjective whether a `switch` results in more readable or less readable code. It can do either, on a case-by-case basis.

---

Special case:

There exists a common optimization of `switch` statements that the compiler can do when all the `case` labels are adjacent integer constants, and that is to replace the whole `switch` with an array of function pointers. It can then simply use the `switch` condition as array index to determine which function to call. No comparisons needed. This is quite a radical optimization, because it removes numerous comparisons and thereby speeds up the code, improves branch prediction, etc.

The very same optimization is possible if you have a chain of `if - else if`, like so:

```
if(n==0)
{ }
else if(n==1)
{ }
else if(n==2)
{ }
...
```

This can also get optimized into an array of function pointers, just like if it were written as a `switch`.

Answer (score 3):

In `case` you've never heard about the "as-if" rule: [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule). That means, **the compiler is allowed to migrate** `if` **to** `switch` **in certain occasions**, yes.

`switch` should be used whenever possible; it gives the compiler more information about the type of data parsed and enables it to construct something like hash tables.
`if` should be used when `switch` cannot be used. That's as easy as it gets.

Comment: "it gives the compiler more information about the type of data parsed" Huh? Why would the compiler not know the type of a variable? Furthermore the compiler is smart enough to construct something like hash tables out if `if-else` too, given that the conditions are compile-time constants. So most of your answer seems rather subjective to me.

Comment: @Lundin By "type" I mean "kind," not really a data type. I'll clarify that.

Answer (score 3):

A c compiler can make any optimisations it likes, so long as the program intent is not altered in any way.

Noting that a `switch` can only occur on integral types, the conversion to a `switch` in your case does appear to be optimal. Trust your optimiser to make such a transformation if appropriate. You can always inspect the output assembly to verify.